# Convert this to lazy_high_chart rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, highcharts

I'd like to convert this demo code to the  lazy_high_chart rails code

Any suggestions?

```
$(function () {

    var colors = Highcharts.getOptions().colors,
        categories = ['MSIE', 'Firefox', 'Chrome', 'Safari', 'Opera'],
        name = 'Browser brands',
        data = [{
                y: 55.11,
                color: colors[0],
                drilldown: {
                    name: 'MSIE versions',
                    categories: ['MSIE 6.0', 'MSIE 7.0', 'MSIE 8.0', 'MSIE 9.0'],
                    data: [10.85, 7.35, 33.06, 2.81],
                    color: colors[0]
                }
            }, {
                y: 21.63,
                color: colors[1],
                drilldown: {
                    name: 'Firefox versions',
                    categories: ['Firefox 2.0', 'Firefox 3.0', 'Firefox 3.5', 'Firefox 3.6', 'Firefox 4.0'],
                    data: [0.20, 0.83, 1.58, 13.12, 5.43],
                    color: colors[1]
                }
            }, {
                y: 11.94,
                color: colors[2],
                drilldown: {
                    name: 'Chrome versions',
                    categories: ['Chrome 5.0', 'Chrome 6.0', 'Chrome 7.0', 'Chrome 8.0', 'Chrome 9.0',
                        'Chrome 10.0', 'Chrome 11.0', 'Chrome 12.0'],
                    data: [0.12, 0.19, 0.12, 0.36, 0.32, 9.91, 0.50, 0.22],
                    color: colors[2]
                }
            }, {
                y: 7.15,
                color: colors[3],
                drilldown: {
                    name: 'Safari versions',
                    categories: ['Safari 5.0', 'Safari 4.0', 'Safari Win 5.0', 'Safari 4.1', 'Safari/Maxthon',
                        'Safari 3.1', 'Safari 4.1'],
                    data: [4.55, 1.42, 0.23, 0.21, 0.20, 0.19, 0.14],
                    color: colors[3]
                }
            }, {
                y: 2.14,
                color: colors[4],
                drilldown: {
                    name: 'Opera versions',
                    categories: ['Opera 9.x', 'Opera 10.x', 'Opera 11.x'],
                    data: [ 0.12, 0.37, 1.65],
                    color: colors[4]
                }
            }];

    function setChart(name, categories, data, color) {
        chart.xAxis[0].setCategories(categories, false);
        chart.series[0].remove(false);
        chart.addSeries({
            name: name,
            data: data,
            color: color || 'white'
        }, false);
        chart.redraw();
    }

    var chart = $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'column'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Browser market share, April, 2011'
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Click the columns to view versions. Click again to view brands.'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: categories
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Total percent market share'
            }
        },
        plotOptions: {
            column: {
                cursor: 'pointer',
                point: {
                    events: {
                        click: function() {
                            var drilldown = this.drilldown;
                            if (drilldown) { // drill down
                                setChart(drilldown.name, drilldown.categories, drilldown.data, drilldown.color);
                            } else { // restore
                                setChart(name, categories, data);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    color: colors[0],
                    style: {
                        fontWeight: 'bold'
                    },
                    formatter: function() {
                        return this.y +'%';
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            formatter: function() {
                var point = this.point,
                    s = this.x +':<b>'+ this.y +'% market share</b><br/>';
                if (point.drilldown) {
                    s += 'Click to view '+ point.category +' versions';
                } else {
                    s += 'Click to return to browser brands';
                }
                return s;
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: name,
            data: data,
            color: 'white'
        }],
        exporting: {
            enabled: false
        }
    })
    .highcharts(); // return chart
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well what can I say, a quick hack simply create a partial with chart.js.erb, copy the above code and insert my values e.g. <%=value%> where I need and render this in the view as a JS file ;-), I am using the gem still but can be bothered translating the gem with missing functionality, this works a charm, dirty but it works

Comment: i couldn't make it work for dynamic data :( i don't know how to fetch it inside js

Comment: use somefilename.js.erb file extension